# Convert a Microsoft Word doc file to HTML file using ASP.NET & C#

Tags: asp.net-ajax

How do I convert a Microsoft Word doc file to HTML file using ASP.NET & C#?

Comment: Use .NET to open the document with Word...and then click Save As...? Seriously, add some detail and and make it look like you TRIED to figure something out on your own...

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
// When we click Button1, the file we specify is uploaded to a temporary
// folder, then converted into an html document...
string folder_to_save_in = @"c:\temp\documents\";
string filePath = folder_to_save_in + FileUpload1.FileName;
// This bit does the actual file upload:
FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);

// Here we set up a WOrd Application...
Word.ApplicationClass wordApplication = new Word.ApplicationClass();

// Opening a Word doc requires many parameters, but we leave most of them blank...
object o_nullobject = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object o_filePath = filePath;
Word.Document doc = wordApplication.Documents.Open(ref o_filePath,
ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject,
ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject,
ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject);

// Here we save it in html format...
// This assumes it was called "something.doc"
string newfilename = folder_to_save_in + FileUpload1.FileName.Replace(".doc", ".html");
object o_newfilename = newfilename;
object o_format = Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatHTML;
object o_encoding = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8;
object o_endings = Word.WdLineEndingType.wdCRLF;
// Once again, we leave many of the parameters blank.
// See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vbawd11/html/womthSaveAs1_HV05213080.asp
// for full list of parameters.
wordApplication.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(ref o_newfilename, ref o_format, ref o_nullobject,
ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject,
ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_encoding, ref o_nullobject,
ref o_nullobject, ref o_endings, ref o_nullobject);

// Report success...
Label1.Text = "Uploaded successfully!";
// Finally, close original...
doc.Close(ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject);
}
}
```

http://www.wherecanibuyit.co.uk/ASP/converting_word_doc_files_to_html.html

Answer (score 1):

by using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace, servers requires Microsoft word to be installed. That i dont want!

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft Word's built-in functionality - "File > Save as Web Page..."

Or, to do this programmatically, use the [`_Document.SaveAs` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.saveas%28office.11%29.aspx) in the [`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word%28office.11%29.aspx).

Comment: is there anyway to create HTML file from doc without using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace?

Comment: Not that I know of; what's the problem with using it?